# Testing image upload with Nightwatch

Tags: testing

I am having trouble figuring out a way to test image upload with Nightwatch. Once I click('.image-upload-button') I am outside the browser into the OS and seem to have no control.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `const path = require('path');` at the top of your file.

You need `.setValue`, as second argument introduce the path to the file in your SO. That will make it.

`.setValue('.selector', path.resolve('path/to/file.jpg'))`