# Upload file using Dropzone in Nigthwatchjs

Tags: javascript, file-upload, nightwatch.js

I've a new requirement within my **nightwatchjs** test script where I need to upload a file within a typical *'Drag or click her to upload'* field.

I've not done an upload test before, so I'm after some help please.

Below is the html for the field where the files are uploaded too, when manually testing this function;

[image]

So, in my nightwatchjs script I currently have the following (taken from an answer given in a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986122/testing-image-upload-with-nightwatch) ;

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
.....

browser.setValue('input.dz-hidden-input', path.resolve('/path to jpeg/filename.jpeg'));
```

but this doesn't appear to work.

It doesn't fail as such (i.e. there are no error messages, and the test doesn't stop), but the file is not uploaded.

I thought I might be referencing the wrong element, so I also tried replacing the element *input.dz-hidden-input* part of the command with;

- div#uploadPanel.dropzone.ember-view.dz-clickable
- div#uploadPanel.dropzone
- .dropzone.ember-view.dz-clickable
- .dropzone

but with no luck.

Am I missing something obvious with this test, or is this upload functionality way, way more complicated in nightwatchjs than a simple setvalue command?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured this out (through trial and error! :) ).

I had the .jpeg directory setup wrong.

Using the following has worked for me;

```
browser.setValue('input.dz-hidden-input', require('path').resolve(__dirname + '/harley-davidson.jpeg'));
```

hope this might help someone else in the future.